# Access VBA how do I combine multiple tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a Access Database with 100 tables. I'd like an easy way to combine all of them into a single query. Is there a way to simply have access select all of them?

For more information:
all the tables have the same number of fields they just have different values in each of them.

I'm new to vba so I don't know where to start with this. All I've found online are examples where you have to name every single table.

Comment: If your 100 tables all have the same fields and contain the same types of values then likely you should have only one table, with an additional field to distinguish which "type" of data a record represents.

Comment: Following from Tim's comment, you can merge all of your tables with something like this: `INSERT INTO [firstTable] SELECT * FROM [secondTable] UNION SELECT * FROM [thirdTable]...`

Comment: No, there is no way to simply have Access select all of them. Also, Access SQL for UNION has a limit of 50 SELECT lines - unless this has been changed since Access 2010.